# NumberFormatException when converting a textfiled input to integer

Tags: java, jtextfield, numberformatexception

I have a `JTextFiled`. and i will be typing some integer values in to it.

I have another method called `getMyAge(int age)` which requires a `int` as a parameter.

I end up having a `NumberFormatException`, when i try to pass the integer that i typed in the textfield.

```
                    getMyAge(Integer.parseInt(txtFiled.getText()));
```

How can i fix this ? (I will at all instances type a Number in to the textfield). I tried the try-catch block but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The exception is thrown by `parseInt()`, which indicates that the text from the text field is cannot be converted to an integer.

Comment: Catch the exception, display an error message.

Comment: I would suggest printing both the exception message and the String you intended to parse.

Comment: What exactly is it that you entered and got the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try printing the content of `txtFiled.getText()` maybe you can try replacing it by `txtFiled.getText().trim()` because an extra empty space can easily cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[**Integer.parseInt(String)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) doc states that

> It would throw NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable
>   integer.

so, most definitely you are passing a string which is not a representation of a number. maybe there is a trailing space appended to the String. Note that :`23` or `23` cannot be parsed because of the whitespaces at the front and end . you could always **trim the whitespaces** with `String.trim()`. If that's the case. try this:

```
                getMyAge(Integer.parseInt(txtFiled.getText().trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

in `parseInt, the exception _NumberFormatException_ is fired, if the string does not contain a parsable integer.` That means in the JTextField what is typed can not be parsed to integer.

### Solution

1. try Catch the exception by a block of `Try/Catch/Finally` and get the message from it.
2. be sure that what is typed in the JTextField is the an integers ... simple :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if textfield contain a number before setting it to setMyAge method.

Suggest you to do something as follows:

```
try {
  setMyAge(Integer.parseInt(txtFiled.getText().trim()));
} catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
  setMyAge(0); // you may remove this line if you doesn't want to set anything.
}
```